# Routing for multiple views in angular and mongodb

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, routes

I am using Yeoman's angular-fullstack and am stuck on making multiple views based on Mongo's auto generated _id. The StoreCtlr, which populates all data to the pag,e works well, I am just having trouble passing in the parameter into the StoreShowCtrl

My controller is below:

```
storeControllers.controller('StoreShowCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams','$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('api/items'+$routeParams.items._id).success(function(detail) {
      $scope.data = detail;
    });
  }
]);
```

I am routing with

```
.when('/product/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'app/product/product.html',
        controller: 'StoreShowCtrl'
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are there any error messages shown?

Answer (score 0):

Use **$routeParams.id** instead **$routeParams.items._id** in controller, as you have mentioned **id**  as param  while defining state. 
This will work.